# How to use get_or_create? Error: get() returned more than one Patient -- it returned 7

Tags: python, django

I have a function for fetch API where I create a Django model object for each object in the JSON and store the data in django model. The problem here is everytime I call the route it creates the records again and again, because I use create method, but I made an research that the best way to stop that is to use get_or_create. So, I tried this method but it looks like I missed something, because I got an error: **feedback.models.Patient.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Patient -- it returned 7!**

this is my code before I have 2 for loops so I can loop through every patient and then through every role and save patient with a role:

```
# FetchApi for Patients def fetchapi_patients(request):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/core/users/roles/patient'
    headers={"Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Imhha2FuQGdvLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTYxMDAxMTM0MSwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE2MTAwMDc3NDF9.k2204d094DNUbEfFt8M_7chukOSjWWwfesPOH5jIiP8"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    #Read the JSON
    patients = response.json()

    #Create a Django model object for each object in the JSON and store the data in django model (in database)
    for patient in patients:
            Patient.objects.create(first_name=patient['first_name'], last_name=patient['last_name'], email=patient['email'], coreapi_id=patient['ID'])
            for role in patient['Roles']:
                Role.objects.create(role_name=role['name'])

    return JsonResponse({'patients': patients})
```

**this is when I tried to use get_or_create method:**

```
for patient in patients:
            patientDatabase, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(first_name=patient['first_name'], last_name=patient['last_name'], email=patient['email'], coreapi_id=patient['ID'])
            for role in patient['Roles']:
                Role.objects.get_or_create(role_name=role['name'])
                

    return JsonResponse({'patients': patients})
```

**this is my models.py:**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    coreapi_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def str(self):
        return self.email

class Role(models.Model):
    role_id = models.ManyToManyField(Patient)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role_name
```

**The Traceback error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/stela/feedbacksystem/feedback/views.py", line 88, in fetchapi_patients
    patientDatabase, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(first_name=patient['first_name'], last_name=patient['last_name'], email=patient['email'], coreapi_id=patient['ID'])   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 538, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 410, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned( feedback.models.Patient.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Patient -- it returned 7!
```

I read the official documentation but there are a some misunderstanding that are not very clear to me about get_or_create method for example I want to check the users only by their email, because I read that it should be something "unique", so get_or_create checks every field in my model or..? I hope my question is clear if it's not please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There simply are multiple objects with the same (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `coreapi_id`), and `get_or_create` refuses to do anything since it's likely a logic problem.

The same would happen with just `.get()` (which is indeed what `.get_or_create()` does).

If you mean to e.g. only get the Patient using the `coreapi_id` field, but if no Patient with that data exists, create them using the other fields, you'll want to use the [`defaults` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create):

```
patientDatabase, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(
    coreapi_id=patient["ID"],
    defaults=dict(
        first_name=patient["first_name"],
        last_name=patient["last_name"],
        email=patient["email"],
    ),
)
```

Comment: So in your example my unique field will be 'ID' and the other arguments are defaults? That makes sense, I tried your example but still get the same error. Also when I loop through their role do I need to get_or_create too?

Comment: That depends on your data model. At any rate, if you've already run `.create()` with the same parameters several times, your database will naturally have multiple copies of the same row. You would need to clean that up (manually?) first.

Comment: What a silly mistake it's my bad! Thank you for the fast reply I marked your answer

Comment: Although to my previous question in the comments for the roles, I need to write them separate and apply the same method right?

Comment: For one I find it very strange that a many-to-many field linking Roles to Patients would be called `role_id`. I think it should be `patients` (assuming one patient can have more than one role; if not, then the Patient object should have a foreign key to Role). After that, `Role.objects.get_or_create(role_name=role['name'])[0].patients.add(patient)` would ensure the linkage.

Comment: I changed the field to patients and setup it with your code and gives me TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict', but the dict was working before and I didn't write inside of it. I set many to many because patient can be patient and employee at the same time

Answer (score 1):

**get_ot_create** method must be only used when something is unique.

in your case, There are multiple objects which are not unique so it is which is returning multiple objects but it should only return one object